# print the smart contract balance using web3

Tags: web3js, truffle, metamask

I am trying to print the balance of the smart contracts using web3 but it doesn't show any error but on the client-side application it appears as follows:

> Your Balance: [object Promise]

/contracts/mycontract.sol:

```
function () external payable {
        // payable fallback to receive and store ETH
        if(msg.value < 10 ether){
        revert();
        }
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;   //this keyword refers to the smart contract address
    }
```

/src/js/app.js:

```
 App.contracts.kyc.deployed().then(function(instance) {
          kycInstance = instance;          
    var bal=kycInstance.getBalance();
              $("#SmartBalance").html("Your Balance: " + bal);
        // #smartbalance is an id for the HTML file
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript function `kycInstance.getBalance` returns a `Promise` object which you need to resolve in order to get the actual value returned from the corresponding Solidity function.

One way to do it, for example, is by changing this:

```
kycInstance.getBalance();
$("#SmartBalance").html("Your Balance: " + bal);
```

To this:

```
kycInstance.getBalance().then(function(bal) {
    $("#SmartBalance").html("Your Balance: " + bal);
});
```

Note that since the Solidity function returns a `uint`, the type of `bal` in Javascript depends on the web3.js version that you're using:

- On web3.js v0.x: `typeof bal == BigNumber`
- On web3.js v1.x: `typeof bal == String`

So if you're using web3.js v0.x, then you would better print `"Your Balance: " + bal.toFixed()`.

Comment: I tried this code, but I am getting an error as follows on the client-side console when I inspect:        Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function